# adjust vertical space between horizontal line of the radix in denominator and the horizontal line of the fraction

Tags: math-mode, spacing, vertical-alignment, fractions

Even in display math I guess that there is too little space between the top horizontal line of the radix symbol and the horizontal line of a `\frac`. How can I control that vertical space?

I have a related question.  When using a radix, the horizontal line becomes to close to the argument of the `\sqrt`.  We can try to fix that by using `\sqrt{\mathstrut x^2 + 3 x}` instead of `\sqrt{x^2 + 3 x}`  but now the vertical space becomes too grandiose!  How can I fix and finetune it very?  I have the impression that these problems are also related by the choice of the font.  I see this problem more pronounced using Lucida math fonts as opposed to Times math fonts.  But anyway, it is good to know how to finetune such things in principle.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You can a;ways use \raisebox to fine tune the vertical spacing (above and below).